# rest query orderby takes null as 0

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, rest, odata, listdata.svc

I am making an ajax call to get the list data in SharePoint 2010

I am using `orderby` to sort based on a column

```
http://PC:2010/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/listName?$select=ThumbnailImage,Created,ListingOrder&$orderby=ListingOrder
```

Here it is sorting based on the `ListingOrder`, but if the `ListingOrder` is `null` then item is coming on the top

How can I make `null` go down and items with values in `ListingOrder` come on top?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I think I made ListingOrder as a choice column and then provided 99999 as the default value

Answer (score 1):

You can use two queries in that case.

1. First query - Get all items filter by ListingOrder not equal NULL
2. Second query - Get all items filter by ListingOrder equal NULL

Apply Order By only on First Query.

Then merge the result sets.

Comment: no other workaround?

Comment: Not sure. Lets wait for some more input from community.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the list contains the following data:

```
ID  ListingOrder
1   1
2   null
3   2
```

Then you could consider the following options:

**Option 1**

The items could be sorted *in descending order*:  `$orderby=ListingOrder desc`, in that case the items for those `listingorder` property is not specified will be listed as the last ones.

Result:

```
ID  ListingOrder
3   2
1   1
2   null
```

**Option 2**

Another option would be to apply sorting to the returned results as demonstrated below:

```
var endpointUrl = 'http://server/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/list?$select=ThumbnailImage,Created,ListingOrder';

$.getJSON(endpointUrl, function(data) {
   var items  = data.d.results;
   items.sort(itemComparer);   //sort by ListingOrder property
   items.forEach(function(item){
     console.log('ListingOrder: ' + item.ListingOrder);    
   });

});

function itemComparer(x,y) {
    if(x.ListingOrder == null || y.ListingOrder == null) return -1;
    return x.ListingOrder > y.ListingOrder;
}
```

Result:

```
ID  ListingOrder
1   1
3   2
2   null
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirement and achieved by using the query like this-

`http://PC:2010/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/listName?$select=ThumbnailImage,Created,ListingOrder&$orderby=(ListingOrder eq null)`